# Swift UITextField not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I just started working on an app and am trying to dynamically add labels and textfields to my view controller's main view, but the textfields just don't show up. I have tried the code below, as well as putting textfields into my storyboard, grabbing them via their tags and then trying to change their frames, but when I try it that way, the frames don't change. I can still tap on the invisible text fields and type in them, but there is no indication that they are there. I feel like it is something really simple that I am just missing. Thanks!

All of the code below is in `viewDidLoad` just after the `super.viewDidLoad()` call

```
let WIDTH = self.view.frame.size.width
let HEIGHT = self.view.frame.size.height
let PADDING:CGFloat = 10
let MAX_PLAYERS = 6
let NAME_X = 2 * PADDING
let FIELD_X = WIDTH / 3
let START_Y:CGFloat = 50
let PLAYER_HEIGHT:CGFloat = 40

for i in 0..<MAX_PLAYERS
{
    let name = UILabel()
    name.text = "Player \(i+1):"
    name.sizeToFit()
    name.frame.origin = CGPointMake(NAME_X, START_Y + (CGFloat(i) * PLAYER_HEIGHT))
    self.view.addSubview(name)

    let fieldFrame = CGRectMake(FIELD_X, START_Y + (CGFloat(i) * PLAYER_HEIGHT), (WIDTH - FIELD_X) - (2 * PADDING), 40)
    let field = UITextField(frame:fieldFrame)
    field.frame = fieldFrame
    field.hidden = false
    self.view.addSubview(field)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Turn on view debugging. Run the project. Go to Xcode > Debug > View Debugging > Show view frames. I am typing this on the go so the wording may not be exact. But try this to see how your controls are sized.

Also, setting borderStyle of the text fields. By default, no borders are shown.

Comment: Setting the borderStyle worked. Seems kind of dumb to have it be invisible by default. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Glad it helped you. I just only found out too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font property of the UILabel and the UITextField

`myLabel.font`

The font property takes a `UIFont` object

Comment: Didn't change anything